# Why p:ajax refresh whole page ? I am using PrimeFace5.0 and JSF 2

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

To be more specific, I want to use disable calendar component when selectOneMenu component change its value!

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="Panel" > 
<p:calendar id="deadLineDate" value="# {projectsControllerCreate.selected.deadLineDate}"  disabled="#{listenerFromSelectOneMenu}" >
</p:calendar>  
 <p:selectOneMenu id="listUrgent" value="#{projectsControllerCreate.selected.listUrgent}">
<p:ajax   update="deadLineDate" event="change" listener="#{bean.listenerFromSelectOneMenu}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

My listenerFromSelectOneMenu looks like this.

```
public boolean listenerFromSelectOneMenu() {
        Date d = deadLine;
        String urg = current.getListUrgent();
        String hackUrg = "";
        hackUrg = (urg==null) ? "":urg;
        return !hackUrg.isEmpty();
    }
```

But **whole page** is refreshing every time!

Comment: What is triggering the refresh?  Is it really the `<p:ajax  event="change"` in your example?  What is the `form` id?

Comment: what do you in your listener... Please read [ask] and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and create an mcve